# Eclipse Metrics Plugin

Tags: eclipse, code-metrics

I'm searching for a Eclipse plugin which measures my activity on projects on a daily basis. I'd like to have a statistic showing me how many LOCs, tests, classes etc. were added. Additionally I'd like it to work without a server.

I'm working with Eclipse 3.7 and 3.6.

Comment: @The People downvoting: no problem with that, but would you please elaborate why?

Comment: @Tonny Madsen: Good question, would be great if I'd have two different figures for that, but if I only have one either one is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't heard of a tool that keeps track of this information and provides deltas, but [CodePro Analytix](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/codepro/doc/index.html) can provide many of these counts on a project (along with several others, as well as performing static analysis). The only metric that you mention that I'm not sure about is counting tests, but you might be able to relate the number of methods in your test packages to a count of the number of tests. It might also provide your historical data as well - I know that it can be used to track historical audit (static analysis) results, but I'm not sure if it keeps a history of measurements.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider Mylyn.  It is a task based plugin for Eclipse.  It lets you get a list of bugs assigned to you...you pick a bug (or create a manual work item), and then Mylyn tracks the time you spend on it.

Time tracking is really just a side benefit of Mylyn, the real power is that it supports automatic context switching..ie. when you get interrupted and have to start working on another bug Mylyn remembers and restores your context.

Comment: I would prefer a code centric and not task centric plugin. Mylyn is great in combination with server side tools like trac, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

[Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) is not an Eclipse plug-in, but it does let you set "checkpoints" to compare how the metrics have changed between checkpoints.  Note that it only works on Windows.